# Is there a way to auto-compile contracts with truffle?

Tags: truffle

Say you have a contract and you want it to watch for changes and run truffle compile --reset. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/269). As of April 2019, this feature is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using an automation library like **gulp**. For example a very basic and easy gulpfile could be the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('run-command', function (cb) {
  exec('truffle compile --reset', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.error(stderr);
    console.log(stdout);

    cb(err);
  });
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('contracts/**/*.sol', ['run-command']);
});


gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.start('watch');
});
```

you can enrich it as you wish. Just install gulp with `npm install gulp` then save the file as `gulpfile.js` and launch gulp with  `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` (or just `gulp`)